# How to avoid N+1 when counting in django

Tags: django

look at the following scenario:

I have an `User` model and an `Address` model that belongs to user.

In the user index, I need to show along with user's info how many addresses does the user have, but it's generating N+1 queries as everytime I call `count` it executes an additional query for that user id.

How can I do that? I read about `select_related` but I'm trying to make it in the reverse order...

In SQL it could be translated to:

```
SELECT user.*,
(SELECT count(*) FROM address WHERE address.user_id = user.id) AS address_count
FROM user
```

Is there a way to get the above SQL with django QuerySet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the number of addresses, you haven't shown your models but you can use the following on your queryset

```
.annotate(address_count=Count('address'))
User.objects.all().annotate(address_count=Count('address'))  # Im guessing you want this
```

This would provide an `address_count` property on for each result

Docs for [`count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#id7)

Comment: @IgorBelo - No worries, enjoy!